# Why does app engine think "requests" is a reserved word suddenly?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

So I just upgraded to Mavericks and I'm suddenly getting all kinds of errors:

Mostly stuff like this:

```
Cannot define property using reserved word 'requests'.
```

We're seeing this with other properties too. None of them are actually reserved words and they're all defined once (so it's not because they're duplicate properties on the same object or via ReferenceProperty fields)

We haven't changed anything (other than the OS upgrade). We're using python2.7, from the app engine log: `Python command: /usr/bin/python2.7` and we specify python27 in the app.yaml

This app (with the same property names) has been live for years, so not sure what's going on. I saw this once trying to set it up on a linux machine, but just gave up then. This time however, it's my main dev machine.

Any ideas?

Longer error:

```
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 515, in __init__
_initialize_properties(cls, name, bases, dct)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 425, in _initialize_properties
check_reserved_word(attr_name)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 319, in check_reserved_word
"definition." % locals())
ReservedWordError: Cannot define property using reserved word 'requests'.
  If you would like to use this name in the datastore consider using a different
  name like requests_ and adding name='requests' to the parameter list of the
  property definition.
```

UPDATE: Downgrading to 2.7.2 seems to fix everything.

Comment: The only change was upgrading to Mavericks? Can you post the exact messages you're seeing?

Comment: That's pretty much the entire error message, posted more above. Yes, only mavericks upgrade.

Comment: Can you provide a short code sample that reproduces this? The upgrade to Mavericks should not have caused this issue. Also, you may want to file a bug about this: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry

Comment: I don't have a Mavericks within reach. What does `python --version` print? This is an odd one. The base code shouldn't trigger this unless some import is stuffing a binding for `request` into the `Model` class. Any chance your code is doing that? Sheer speculation at this point, but I'm guessing that import ordering might be involved.

Comment: It's python version: 2.7.5

Comment: I tracked down a Mac that had been upgraded to Mavericks and poked at it, but don't (yet?) see that Mavericks is implicated.

Comment: As I mentioned above, it also happens on linux. I've looked into the code that's erroring (check_reserved_word) any idea why it would think requests is a reserved word. it looks like it also checks for duplicates, but we don't have duplicate requests properties.

Comment: Downgrading to 2.7.2 seems to fix everything.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the source for "check_reserved_word".
I grabbed latest & took a peek at python/google/appengine/ext/db/_*init*_py

It's **not** that *requests* is a Python reserved word, it's that *requests* is now reserved by *GoogleAppEngine*.

```
if attr_name in _RESERVED_WORDS or attr_name in dir(Model):
  raise ReservedWordError(
    "Cannot define property using reserved word '%(attr_name)s'. "
    "If you would like to use this name in the datastore consider "
    "using a different name like %(attr_name)s_ and adding "
    "name='%(attr_name)s' to the parameter list of the property "
    "definition." % locals())
```

If you are curious as to how AppEngine is using 'requests', you should look at where **_RESERVED_WORDS** is set, as well as the contents of **dir(Model)**.